# Single iPhone app to multiple iPhones destibution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, distribution

I am developing an iPhone application for car dealers who would register with my website, which will let them add details of their cars and photos and push them into my website. I want to hand them out each an iPhone with the application installed (at least 100 dealers). I want to know whether it is possible to be done using one apple account (since the max limitation is 5 devices to be used with one apple ID). Or please suggest me another alternative for this?

I want this to be done in a proper way so they would be able to receive updates of the application as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: if these are your iPhones register your company for the Enterprise Distribution Program. If your app is useful to a hundred people only it probably won't make it to the app store. Apple will tell you to get an enterprise account. You should really contact apple about this.

Comment: a second idea: So the app should publish details to a website. Is this a website for everybody? Then you could put the "get details from website"-part into the same app. Regular users could see the details, and when you have an account on your website you can push details to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Ad-Hoc Distribution (part of your Apple Developer Program) you can install your app on up to 100 devices. If you sign up for the Enterprise Apple Developer Program, you will no longer have a device limit but will violate the program if you use it to distribute outside your organization.

The other option is to publish your app to the App Store and protect it with a username/password so that only car dealers you authorize can access your app.

Comment: Great, I will look into it. But the second option doesnt address the limitation issue does it?

Comment: can you have an app that only works if you subscribe to an outside website?  (I was not sure about this, if there was no way to join)

Comment: sure you can have an app that only works when you are registered to a service. Think Twitter, think Facebook. But you probably can't have an app in the app store that can be used by a couple of hundred people only.

Comment: nycynik - probably not.  Apple require a reasonably broad audience, so such an app would have to offer some level of service before login was required.

Comment: @kevboh looks like Enterprise Apple Developer Program is the way to go. If I have the car dealer in a contract with me, they wont be outside the organization would they? Since i will be handing over the iphones from my company.

Comment: @blackpla9ue You should be fine. Ideally if the car dealers are all a member of a specific organization or dealership, you purchase the program in their name using their identification.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the closed nature of the iPhone, there isn't a neat way that you can distribute devices with apps preinstalled besides building them as developer versions before shipping.  These will expire over time and you would be limited to 100 deployments as per the number of unique devices allowed per iOS developer account.

Comment: Yes I thought about this before, but then pushing the updates would be a problem right? Nevertheless thanks again for the answer

Comment: Yes, once you hand over the device you could no longer update them.  You could look at https://testflightapp.com/ as a potential solution, but even this requires accounts to be set up which you would need to hand over.

Comment: Just keep in mind that it is against apples rules to use ad-hoc distribution for something that is not related to development. Ad-Hoc is not small scale non-appstore distribution. It's purpose is solely to test apps for development.

Comment: This isn't true. The Enterprise Program exists specifically to address this need.

Comment: Sure, I was talking about the Ad-Hoc distribution in the non-enterprise developer program.

Comment: Even the Enterprise Program isn't suited - you can only distribute to members within a single organisation.  Being able to formally gift devices with apps preinstalled would be a great feature for Apple to support - I've seen this done informally by several companies but it's prone to all the problems mentioned above!

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I was commenting in reply to the answer, not your comment :)